# How would an improved "read receipt" work as an email, Facebook post, or webpage?

Tags: cryptography, drm

I'm exploring various ways to implement cryptographic read receipts, that would be used to tell the content producer that the content was viewed.  In addition to feedback reporting, a response might also provide a decryption key useful for the client to decrypt additional content.

Both the advertisement and featured content could be

- An email
- Facebook post
- Video (advertisement?)
- Webpage

etc.

Said another way, my strategy is to embed a redemption code within the advertisement, which would then unlock the content of interest.

I believe a variant of broadcast encryption could be used, or perhaps even DRM could be leveraged to accomplish this.

Is there any previous implementation, field of study, or thought I should search for prior to assembling something of my own creation?

Comment: If your question is "how can I design a message system where the recipient can only read a message if they have also sent a receipt", it has already been asked somewhere on the stackexchange network, I couldn't find a link though. The answer involved making sender and recipient exchange single bits of according decryption keys (for the actual message and its receipt), where, if one decides to be "evil" and acts as if the connection broke, they end out with one bit of their key more, having it twice as easy to brute-force the content.

Comment: I remember seeing something similar too, but I can't find it.  Hopefully it wasn't deleted.

Comment: You might be able to force people to download and even decrypt your commercials before they can access your actual content, but you can not force them to watch them. As a content provider you don't have that kind of control over the users computer.